# How can I test a custom Flask error page?

Tags: python, flask

I'm attempting to test a custom error page in flask (`404` in this case).

I've defined my custom 404 page as such:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    print "Custom 404!"
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

This works perfectly when hitting an unknown page in a browser (I see `Custom  404!` in stdout and my custom content is visible). However, when trying to trigger a 404 via `unittest` with `nose`, the standard/server 404 page renders. I get no log message or the custom content I am trying to test for.

My test case is defined like so:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app.config.from_object('config.TestConfiguration')
        self.app.debug = False # being explicit to debug what's going on...
        self.app_context.push()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_custom_404(self):
        path = '/non_existent_endpoint'
        response = self.client.get(path)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
        self.assertIn(path, response.data)
```

I have `app.debug` explicitly set to `False` on my test app. Is there something else I have to explicitly set?

Comment: Can you please post your unit test code?

Comment: you have to set `TESTING` explicitly to `True`. It also depends how you set up your logger.

Comment: We would need to see you are testing hitting an endpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After revisiting this with fresh eyes, it's obvious that the problem is in my initialization of the application and not in my test/configuration. My app's `__init__.py` basically looks like this:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfiguration')
    app.secret_key = app.config.get('SECRET_KEY')
    app.register_blueprint(main.bp)
    return app

app = create_app()

# Custom error pages

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Notice that the error handler is attached to `@app` outside of `create_app()`, the method I'm calling in my `TestCase.setUp()` method.

If I simply move that error handler up into the `create_app()` method, everything works fine... but it feels a bit gross? Maybe?

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfiguration')
    app.secret_key = app.config.get('SECRET_KEY')
    app.register_blueprint(main.bp)

    # Custom error pages
    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def page_not_found(e):
        return render_template('404.html'), 404

    return app
```

This ultimately answers my question and fixes my problem, but I'd love other thoughts on how to differently register those errorhandlers.

Comment: In your MyTestCase class, after you call create_app, you can also do `self.app.register_error_handler(404, page_not_found)` (you will also need to import that method separately in your test file). This lets you keep your original file unmodified, but you have to do two extra lines in your test file (one for the import, one for the register_error_handler)... I too feel like this is an imperfect solution as the flask test_client() should do this automatically... the best solution might be to override that method with super and to specifically register any methods with the errorhandler decorator.

Comment: Why not create a Blueprint specifically for errors and then you just need to register the blueprint to your app?

Comment: for 404 just go to your-app-url/a-page-that-is-not-in-my-code

Answer (score 1):

The Flask application object has an `error_handler_spec` property that can be mocked to solve this:

> A dictionary of all registered error handlers. The key is None for
> error handlers active on the application, otherwise the key is the
> name of the blueprint. Each key points to another dictionary where the
> key is the status code of the http exception. The special key None
> points to a list of tuples where the first item is the class for the
> instance check and the second the error handler function.

So something like this in your test method should work:

```
mock_page_not_found = mock.magicMock()  
mock_page_not_found.return_value = {}, 404

with mock.patch.dict(self.app.error_handler_spec[None], {404: mock_page_not_found}):
  path = '/non_existent_endpoint'
  response = self.client.get(path)

  self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
  mock_page_not_found.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: Not sure if there was an API change, but for me, something similar to `from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest` then `{400: {BadRequest: mock_bad_request}}` worked.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the following comment you made "If I simply move that error handler up into the create_app() method, everything works fine... but it feels a bit gross? Maybe?":
You can define a function to register an error handler and call that in your create_app function:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.BaseConfiguration')
    app.secret_key = app.config.get('SECRET_KEY')
    app.register_blueprint(main.bp)
    register_error_pages(app)
    return app

app = create_app()

# Custom error pages

def register_error_pages(app):
    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def page_not_found(e):
        return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

That way if you have more custom error handlers you want to register (403, 405, 500) you can define them inside the register_error_pages function instead of your create_app function.